# F# - using relative path for a data catalog in a connection string

Tags: sql, visual-studio, f#

Hello I have attached a local DB to my visual studio project but I can't make my absolute path relative.

I have a project with a .fs file located at

```
C:\USERS\SOME_USER\SOLUTION_FOLDER\DIRECTORY\FIRST_PROJECT\file.fs
```

In this file I am trying to use a local databse with a catalog in another project and so the generated connection is

```
@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=C:\USERS\SOME_USER\SOLUTION_FOLDER\DIRECTORY\OTHER_PROJECT\APP_DATA\LOCALDATABASE.MDF; Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=15; Encrypt=False; TrustServerCertificate=False"
```

This works wonders

Then I tried to make the path to the catalog relative like this  `"..\OTHER_PROJECT\APP_DATA\LOCALDATABASE.MDF"` but that wont work.

The compiled file.fs should be in `C:\USERS\SOME_USER\SOLUTION_FOLDER\DIRECTORY\FIRST_PROJECT\BIN\DEBUG\`
Which got me thinking that the compiled files need to go 3 directories out and so I have also tried with this catalog
`"..\..\..\OTHER_PROJECT\APP_DATA\LOCALDATABASE.MDF"` which wont work either.

So I am a bit unsure what to do.

Oh, and the error I am getting when trying a relative path:

```
ERROR: Error reading schema. ERROR: Cannot open database.
```

-
MJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFileName.mdf;InitialCatalog=DatabaseName …
```

The string `|DataDirectory|` expands to the `App_Data` folder of the project (this is done by a setting within the SQL Server support in ADO.NET so is language independent).

You should be able to use `..` after the `|DataDirectory|`, otherwise you need to find how to however how that expands (I recall working this out, but it was a long time ago).